# Can't read the embedded font ESNOYH+Calibri-Bold in pdf reading

Tags: scala, pdfbox, pdf-reader

I tried below code for reading the pdf :

```
val byteArrayOutPutStream: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val file = new File(path + name)
    val inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
    val document = new PDFDocumentReader(inputStream)
    var result: List[BufferedImage] = Nil
    val numPgs = document.getNumberOfPages

    for (i <- 0 until numPgs) {
      val pageDetail = new PageDetail("", "", i, "")
      val resourceDetails = document.getPageAsImage(pageDetail)

      val image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(resourceDetails.getBytes()))
      result ::= image
    }
```

But in a particular pdf, I am getting following error :

```
Oct 24, 2013 10:48:01 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont getawtFont
INFO: Can't read the embedded font ESNOYH+Calibri-Bold
Oct 24, 2013 10:48:01 AM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
WARNING: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.getawtFont(PDTrueTypeFont.java:427)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.drawString(PDSimpleFont.java:97)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.processTextPosition(PageDrawer.java:190)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(PDFStreamEngine.java:494)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:62)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:551)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:274)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:251)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:225)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:107)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:722)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:693)
    at org.dopdf.document.read.pdf.PDFPage.asImage(PDFPage.java:59)
```

How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a known issue [PDFBOX-490: Pdf Printing of text from embedded fonts](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-490) that's been fixed. But the fixed version 2.0.0 I don't think is released yet.